# Quiero imprimir los valores que tengo guardado en un arreglo en un Jtextfield

Tags: java, array, poo, interfaz-gráfica

Como mencione en el titulo solo quiero tomar los elementos que tengo en un arreglo y pasarlos a un JTextField. Tengo una interfaz que se llama configurar donde inserto los valores a mi arreglo y el tamaño. Esto lo hago con una clase auxiliar donde tengo metodos gets y set para guardarlos. Mi problema es que cuando continuo a mi interfaz de juego no me aparece nada cuando llamo mis métodos como si estuvieran vació.

Me pidieron que anexara mi ejecución del programa lo agrego:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les anexo mi código:

Interfaz Configurar

```
package d2_craps;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class CONFIGURAR extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private String[] nombres;
    DATOS dt = new DATOS();
     
    /**
     * Creates new form CONFIGURAR
     */
    public CONFIGURAR() {
        initComponents();
    }

 private void AgregarNombActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
       nombres = new String[dt.getNumJugador()]; // Inicializo nuestro array y le doy el tamaño del vector.
       String dato;
       for (int i = 0; i < dt.getNumJugador(); i++) {
           dato = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Ingrese el nombre del jugador: " + (i+1));
           nombres[i] = dato;
       }
       dt.setNombres(nombres);    
       
      DefaultTableModel modelo=(DefaultTableModel) tbl_Jugadores.getModel(); 
      Object [] fila=new Object[2];
      
      for (int j = 0; j < dt.getNumJugador(); j++){
        fila[0]=j+1;
        fila[1]= dt.getNombres()[j];
        modelo.addRow(fila);
      }
      tbl_Jugadores.setModel(modelo);
      
    } 

  private void cmb_jugadoresActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         dt.setNumJugador(cmb_jugadores.getSelectedIndex()+1);
    }                                             

    private void bt_continuarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        INTERFAZ_CRAPS craps = new INTERFAZ_CRAPS();
        craps.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Les paso el código relevante a mis metodos.

```
public class DATOS {
    
    private int ronda;                     //AQUI GUARDARE LA RONDA
    private int numJugador;                //AQUI GUARDAR EL NUMERO DE JUGADORE
    private int tiros[][];                //MATRIZ QUE GUARDA LA RONDA Y TIRO
    private String nombres[];             //AQUI GUARDARE EL NOMBRE DEL JUGADOR
    

    public DATOS() {                        //EN EL CONSTRUCTOR INICIALIZO MIS VARIABLES EN 0 Y CADENA VACIA
        this.ronda = 0;
        this.numJugador = 0;
    }
    
    public String NOMBRES (){
      return nombres[numJugador];      
    }
    
    public String[] getNombres(){
      return Arrays.copyOf(nombres, nombres.length);
    }
    
    public void setNombres(String[] newArrayNomb){
      this.nombres = Arrays.copyOf(newArrayNomb, newArrayNomb.length);
    } 
 
  public int getRonda() {                          
        return ronda;
    }

    public void setRonda(int ronda) {
        this.ronda = ronda;
    }
    
    public int getNumJugador() {                          
        return numJugador;
    }

    public void setNumJugador(int numJugador) {
        this.numJugador = numJugador;
    }    
  
}
```

Interfaz de juego. Les paso la parte relevante donde quiero pasar mi arreglo.

```
 public INTERFAZ_CRAPS() {
        initComponents();
    
//   nombres[dt.getNumJugador()] = dt.getNombres();
if(dt.getNumJugador()==0){
    txt_nom1.setText("Vacio");
} else {
   for (int i =0; i<= dt.getNumJugador(); i++){   
    txt_nom1.setText(String.valueOf(dt.getNombres()[i]));
} 
    }

txt_ronda.setText(""+Integer.toString(dt.getNumJugador()));

}
```

Comment: Todos los métodos los generaste tu?? o estas usando algún `IDE` como `NetBeans`, `Eclipse` o `IntellIj Idea`??

Comment: Puedes agregar un ejemplo de los datos que ingresas y como se muestra???

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo con netbeans.